# using two getline(cin,s) in c++

Tags: c++, string, cin, getline

There's something wrong with my code. I typed something and pressed enter after seeing "the first string"on the screen but I saw a empty new line instead of "the second string". Then I typed something again and pressed enter again. Then I had no chance to enter the second string and got the output directly. I have tried cin.ignore() but it didn't work.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

void main() {
    using namespace std;
    string str1;
    string str2;

    cout << "the first string" << endl;
    getline(cin,str1);
    cout << "the second string" << endl;
    getline(cin,str2);
    cout << str1 << endl << str2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't compile for me because `void main()` must be `int main()`. Once I fixed that, it worked just fine.

Comment: You'll get a compiler warning on most compilers for `void main()`, but the real issue is likely to be that you aren't checking to make sure the input stream is still valid, or that you aren't entering a line (that is you aren't pressing "ENTER" after your first input).  [Example](http://ideone.com/B9mHmW)

Comment: Hi Zac, I have tried your code but I still had to enter two lines for the first getline statement.But thank you.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have changed void main()to int main() but it still didn't work. But Thank you .

Comment: what do you mean by two lines? what compiler are you using? In Xcode (LLVM 5.0) I got http://ideone.com/0rBDRO, which is what I was expecting.

Comment: Is this your entire program? Try doing `getline(cin >> ws, str1) ... getline(cin >> ws, str2)`. If that doesn't work try inputting Ctrl-D at the end of your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version of flushing the input buffer. This may or may not be the solution in your case, but it is worth a try:

```
//code code code
cin.ignore( cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() );
getline(cin,str1);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore( cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() );
getline(cin,str2);
cin.clear();

//code code code
```

Comment: No, there're still two lines for each getline statement.But thank you.